# jQuery How to write text to ID selector - multiple ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My div has two ID and I'm trying to add text to these div with use one id selector. How to do?

jQuery

```
function fn(k) {
    $('#' + k).text('test')
};
```

html

```
<div id="a b"><script>fn('b');</script></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID should be unique across the HTML page. You can have multiple classes though.

So,

`<div id="a b"><script>fn('b');</script></div>` is **wrong**.

`<div class="a b"><script>fn('b');</script></div>` is **right**.

Hope its clear.

To select the classes using JQuery do something like -

`$( ".myClass" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );`

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

You can never have more than one id for the element.